# Android Accessibility reading out "Double Tap to Select" additionally

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a 
`RelativeLayout`

Inside that I have two `TextView` and an `Imageview`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_statement_email_alert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <customviews.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_statement_emailalert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/statement_alert_email"
        android:textColor="@color/accounts_darkgray_text"
        custom:typeface="Tahoma" />

    <customviews.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_statement_alertby_email_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_double"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/accounts_darkgray_text"
        custom:typeface="Tahoma" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icn_blue"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I turn on Talkback to ON section,
It reads out the "Email" text along with the available email id(which is expected). But additionally it says "Double tap to select" on the layout also(this is unexpected).

I am not being able to figure out why it says "Double tap to select" additionally when I have set the `android:contentDescription="@null"`.

Any help will be appreciated. I am checking in Nexus 7 Tab and Nexus 6 Moto Phone, both having Android 6.0

Answer (score 1):

TalkBack speaks the interaction model if the user continues to hover over an view. This is correct behavior, and you should not attempt to prevent or override it.